# Mac OS X web server suddenly forbidden

Tags: macos, apache, web, osx-mavericks

tl;dr - Hosted and developed a website in a custom folder with no issues; changed folder and now image subfolder is 403 forbidden.

I had developed a website with PHP/HTML using the Server app on Mac OS X 10.9.4. Setting up the server was amazingly easy, I just turned "Websites" on and chose the folder to serve as the root folder.

Now, I want to start developing a second website, so I just went in and changed the "Store Files In" folder to a different folder. Now the subfolder "images" is coming up 403 forbidden.

I've tried creating a new folder and using that as root, as well as using a fresh ~/Sites folder, and the images subfolder is still forbidden, and any reference to an image comes up broken.

NOTE: I've already searched Google as well as Stack Overflow for solutions to this and none of the solutions have worked for me, including modifying and creating .conf files, chmodding the crap out of everything and restarting Apache through Terminal numerous times.